# How to deliver WP app to customer without publishing in Marketplace?

Tags: windows-phone-7, publishing, marketplace

Now, to deliver each build to customer, i am publishing it on marketplace as beta version, so only i and customer can download it. Submission requires about 24h.

Is there any other way to install build to customer's phone to avoid this time lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to possibly do this is to register the client's device under your app hub developer account and deploy it manually.

This is not ideal.

Unfortunately there is no side-loading concept (or at least wasn't as part of WP 7.5) that allows you to ignore the app store.

[This particular link](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/46174/windows-phone-8-detailed-new-features) suggests that side-loading will exist in WP8, though I personally don't know if it is enabled.

Comment: Side loading is only possible for signed apps downloaded from the marketplace or for enterprise distribution

Comment: @MattLacey On Windows (and Phone) 8?

Comment: Yes, you can install via an SD card for WP8 if the app is from the marketplace. See http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/how-do-i-install-apps-from-an-sd-card and http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/16305_Side_load_app_and_game_xap_via.php